# Layout Changes by Changing Screen Resolution Strange CSS Issue

Tags: html, css, css-float

Website Under Discussion:  http://staging.vansanws.in/alibrown/

When I change resolution(**zooming the page using 'ctrl' + '+'**) of this page (http://staging.vansanws.in/alibrown/) **layout of menu changes** . It's size somehow increases and it comes in next line on some resolutions.

I also had this problem before working on some other website. But every time I just reduce the size of element to avoid an major layout change. But this time I though to find out **real reson for this strange behavious**

**This happen in all browsers(IE, Chrome, Firefox)**

**By changing resolution I mean Zooming in the window using 'Ctrl' + '+'**

Comment: What do you mean with "changing the resolution of the page"? Do you mean resizing the browser window or "zoom" into the page? Furthermore: Which browser?

Comment: @cem By changing resolution I mean zooming the page that we do using ctrl & + at a time..it is happening on FF, IE and chrome.

Comment: In this case: the last menu entry is already in the next line when I open the page. Using Safari on OS X.

Comment: @cem hmm as I said at some resolutions(zoom point) it goes to next line.... if you'll change resolutions(zoom) you'll see it moves up and down randomly.

Comment: Yes, because the space the floating elements need to float in one line is larger than the available space. This can happen, if the rendering of the text is slightly different and need a single pixel more. Work – straight down – with relative values like em to make sure, the positioning of your elements wont be affected by zoom levels.

Comment: Zooming in is not the same as changing resolution. Zooming in distorts a lot of things, and for testing on different resolutions you have to resize your browser window instead. (p.s. you can set specific browser sizes/resolutions in the 'Web Developer Toolbar' which is a add-on downloadable for Chrome and Firefox).

Comment: @cem I use px normally but I tested with em values too, Even then the menu is ok at some points and NOT ok at some points.

Comment: @poepje same thing happens (menu items size increase and it comes over to the second line) if I resize using web developer tools add on in FF,....

Comment: That's too bad.. Your issue doesn't occur in my FF though, strangely enough. Which version are you using? I use FF 16.0.2.